# JavaFX modify the coordinates of a given mesh in real time

Tags: javafx, mesh

I would like to modify the coordinates of a given mesh in real time in JavaFX which is triangulated. Is is possible ?

I can not think of a way to do so, just to reinitialize the points all over again in a MeshView which is not correct.

I would like something like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqAa8Uu9zbQ&index=9&list=PLvPs0rMPHQHcoN-dPnXXvETarhsUNz5oO

Does somebody have an ideea?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems straight-forward, you just [get the points](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html#getPoints--) and you change them.  It's difficult to know what you are doing wrong without code.  If you are continuing to experience difficulties, please edit the question to include [the code for your failed attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that the point array is an [ObservableFloatArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableFloatArray.html), so whenever you update a point in the array, the related mesh should deform accordingly.

Comment: oh so the array is an ObservableFloatArray.The bad part is the fact that I have to keep track of the index the array of points.

Comment: [Cross-posted to javaranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/667404/JavaFX/java/JavaFX-modify-coordinates-mesh-real).